# Jet bundle cohomology

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology, classical-mechanics, fiber-bundles

Consider a base manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and a smooth bundle $E\to\mathcal{M}$. I am interested in the cohomology groups of the variational bicomplex associated with the jet bundle $J^{\infty}E$. In particular, if $d$ is the exterior derivative over $\mathcal{M}$ and $\delta$ is the variational derivative, given that we know the structure of $E$, what can we say about the cohomology of $J^{\infty}E$ induced by $\delta$?

Comment: You can find information about the cohomology of the variational complex in G. Sardanashvily, *Advanced Differential Geometry for Theoreticians* (Lambert, 2013), Chapter 7 ("Lagrangian Theory").